# Skiing near Bangalore?

Tags: india, bangalore, skiing

I know that most of the skiing in India is up in the Himalayas, but given that Bangalore is quite high to start with (~900m), and there are higher hill stations nearby... Is there anywhere near to Bangalore where it's possible to ski? Or is the only option to take a train/fly all the way up to the north of India?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bangalore has a higher-than-average elevation over sea level because it's part of a plateau - the [Deccan Plateau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deccan_Plateau). This elevation and local weather conditions do not cause snowfall in the region. The highest mountains in the vicinity are part of the [Nilgiri mountain range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilgiri_mountains) and they don't really get any snow (if my memory of geography class and my travels around Nilgiris serve me right).  In fact, [with the exception of the Himalayas range, there are hardly any skiing sites in India](http://www.snow-forecast.com/countries/India/resorts).

Answer (score 6):

[Weather Forecast](http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/Bangalore) site gives ski resorts close to Bangalore:

- Closest ski resort:   Auli (India)    1968 km
- Second closest ski resort:    Kufri (India)   2027 km
- Third closest ski resort:     Manali (Himachal Heli-Ski) (India)  2147 km
- Fourth closest ski resort:    Solang Valley Ropeway & Ski Centre (India)  2152 km
- Fifth closest ski resort:     Gulmarg (India)     2367 km

It also gives mountains close to Bangalore:

- Closest mountain peak:    Doddabetta (India)  197 km
- Second closest mountain peak:     Nilgiri mountains (India)   199 km
- Third closest mountain peak:  Mullayanagiri (India)   207 km
- Fourth closest mountain peak:     Pushpagiri (India)  208 km
- Fifth closest mountain peak:  Brahmagiri (hill) (India)   210 km